# Rodrigues' formula for vector rotation

Tags: javascript, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to do the rodrigues' formula for rotation around an arbitrary axis for some angle. I have this code

```js
function norm(v) {
    return Math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2]);
}
function normalize(v) {
    var length = norm(v);
    return [v[0]/length, v[1]/length, v[2]/length];
}
function dotProduct(v1, v2) {
    return v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1] + v1[2]*v2[2];
}
function crossProduct(v1, v2) {
    return [v1[1]*v2[2] - v1[2]*v2[1], v1[2]*v2[0] - v1[0]*v2[2], v1[0]*v2[1] - v1[1]*v2[0]];
}
function getAngle(v1, v2) {
    return Math.acos(dotProduct(v1, v2) / (norm(v1)*norm(v2)));
}
function matrixMultiply(matrix, v) {
    return [dotProduct(matrix[0], v), dotProduct(matrix[1], v), dotProduct(matrix[2], v)];
}
function aRotate(p, v, a) {
    var ca = Math.cos(a), sa = Math.sin(a), t=1-ca, x=v[0], y=v[1], z=v[2];
    var r = [
        [ca + x*x*t, x*y*t - z*sa, x*z*t + y*sa],
        [x*y*t + z*sa, ca + y*y*t, y*z*t - x*sa],
        [z*x*t - y*sa, z*y*t + x*sa, ca + z*z*t]
    ];
    return matrixMultiply(r, p);
}

var v1 = [5,-6,4];
var v2 = [8,5,-30];
var a = getAngle(v1, v2);
var cp = crossProduct(v1, v2);
var ncp = normalize(cp);
var np = aRotate(v1, ncp, a);
console.log(np); // <---- this is wrong result
```

So I start with 2 vectors, I get the angle between them, I get the perpendicular vector, and normalize it, then I test my matrix, and see if I get back v2 if I input v1. But I don't get it back. Does anyone know where I went wrong. I think it is in the matrix code. I get back `[2.232221073308228, 1.3951381708176427, -8.370829024905852]`.

Formula is here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
under **Rotation matrix from axis and angle**

Thanks

Comment: I set you up with a basic testing framework you can use to debug further. Please use this to compare your "expected" value with the values you're receiving. http://jsbin.com/howosuwova/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem here.

`np` is a vector of the correct direction (same direction as `v2`) but the wrong magnitude. You can see with:

```
console.log(normalize(v2), normalize(np));
```

The result is:

`[0.254385200299, 0.1589907501872, -0.953944501123]
[0.254385200299, 0.1589907501872, -0.953944501123]`

`v2` can be found with `norm(v2) * normalize(np)`.

---

Because `v1` and `v2` are very different lengths, rotating `v1` will only get you the correct direction, but the length of the resulting vector will still have the length of `v1`. You can see this with:

`console.log(norm(v1), norm(np));`

returns:

`8.774964387392123
8.774964387392123`

Comment: Then `rotate` is not the right tool for the job. The function you posted rotates just fine!

Comment: Oh ok, I forgot that they were different lengths, that is the issue.